# None required PathVariable not working

Tags: spring, parameters, option-type

I got the following code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user/{username}/{auth_key}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ProfileRequest getUser(final @PathVariable("username") String username,
                              final @PathVariable(value = "auth_key", required = false) UUID authKey) {
```

and I can't understand why /user/{username} does not handle my request.

Mfg.

Comment: what is happening? are u getting any exception ?

Comment: No, i don't get any errors. The server returns just a simple 404 error with the message "No message available"

Comment: Can you show the request url? If the pathVariable is not required perhaps you missed a slash at the end of the request url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**/user/{username}/{auth_key}** and **/user/{username}** are different URLs. Putting all these URLs to @GetMapping annotation will resolve your problem:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/user/{username}/{auth_key}", "/user/{username}/"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```